# SQL Server + conditional updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, sql-update

I have an update statement like this which tries to perform an update. In my SPROC, I will either pass in one of the 2 parameters(@TransactAutoID or @ReceiptNo) or both. What I want to do is if @TransactAutoID is empty then I will use the @ReceiptNo instead as a 2nd choice alternative to do it. Is there a better or more efficient way of writing it because from my understanding, the 'OR' operator will still proceed to perform this:

```
OR  (@ReceiptNo IS NOT NULL AND [AutoID] = (SELECT Max(AutoID)  
                                                FROM   [Transact]
                                                WHERE  [ReceiptNo] = @ReceiptNo)
```

even if @TransactAutoID is not null. Thanks.

```
 UPDATE  [Transact]
    SET     [VoidBy]     = @VoidedBy,
            [VoidOn]     = Getdate(),
            [VoidReason] = @VoidedReason
    WHERE   (@TransactAutoID IS NOT NULL 
              AND [AutoID] = @TransactAutoID)
        OR  (@ReceiptNo IS NOT NULL AND [AutoID] = (SELECT Max(AutoID)  
                                                    FROM   [Transact]
                                                    WHERE  [ReceiptNo] = @ReceiptNo)
```

Comment: You can write this as two separe update statements, one for each condition.  Use t-SQL logic to determine the right one to use.

Comment: If you want "both" updates to occur as a single transaction then you need to use either a single statement (as you have done) or an explicit transaction around two updates.

Answer (score 1):

Just add @TransactAutoID IS NULL in your second statement - and possibly the opposite in the first statement - depending on your logic (e.g. if you pass both, are you expecting it to do something differnt or fail or what?)

e.g.

```
UPDATE  [Transact] 
SET     [VoidBy]     = @VoidedBy, 
        [VoidOn]     = Getdate(), 
        [VoidReason] = @VoidedReason 
WHERE   (@TransactAutoID IS NOT NULL AND @ReceiptNo IS NULL
          AND [AutoID] = @TransactAutoID) 
    OR  (@TransactAutoID IS NULL AND @ReceiptNo IS NOT NULL AND [AutoID] = (SELECT Max(AutoID)   
                                                FROM   [Transact] 
                                                WHERE  [ReceiptNo] = @ReceiptNo)
```